Salesforce code analyzer DFA
Im hitting a strange error when running the salesforce code analyzer DFA report -
sf scanner run dfa --format csv --outfile CodeAnalyzerDFA.csv --target ./ --projectdir ./ --category Security
Scanner version: v3.25.0
The scanner seems to be flagging every method that returns a custom object, or uses a custom object with the below error, looking at the error it seems to point DescribeSObjectResult which suggests that the analyzer is having trouble accessing the SObjectType, for the example below the source line of the error in the output points to the method declaration.
Am I doing something wrong here?
For a security review I need to submit clean reports / document false positives is this a false positive?
Example method:
public static list<Custom_Object_Link__c> getObjectLinks(string ObjectId){
    list<Custom_Object_Link__c> fields = new List<Custom_Object_Link__c>();

    //string array that contains all of the fields needed 
    String[] accessFields = objectLinkFields();
    
    //method check fls 
    if (!DatabaseFLS.flsSelect('nmspace__Custom_Object_Link__c', accessFields)) {
        throw new RevCPQCustomException('log Error accessing fields. Check that the user has the required rights.');
    }

    //string that contains all fields to search for
    string query = objectLinkQueryFields();

    query = query + ' from nmspace__Custom_Object_Link__c where nmspace__CPQ_Object_Id__c =: ObjectId  Order By nmspace__CPQ_Object_Selected__c DESC, nmspace__CPQ_Object_Valid__c DESC';
    fields = Database.query(query);
    system.debug('log return [' + fields.size() +'] fields for connection.');
    return fields;
} 

Database flsSelect:
    public static Boolean flsSelect (String flsSObject, String[] accessFields) {
        SObjectType r = ((SObject)(Type.forName('Schema.' + flsSObject).newInstance())).getSObjectType();
        DescribeSObjectResult flsDescribe = r.getDescribe();
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = flsDescribe.fields.getMap();

        Boolean flsAccessibleFlag = true;

        for(String fieldToCheck : accessFields)
        {        
            if (!mfields.get(fieldToCheck).getDescribe().isAccessible()){
                flsAccessibleFlag = false;
                break;
            } else {
                flsAccessibleFlag = true;
            }
        }

        if (flsAccessibleFlag) {
            return flsAccessibleFlag;
        }
        else {
            return flsAccessibleFlag;
        }
    }

Error:
Graph Engine identified your source and sink, but you must manually verify that you have a sanitizer in this path. Then, add an engine directive to skip the path. Next, create a Github issue for the Code Analyzer team that includes the error and stack trace. After we fix this issue, check the Code Analyzer release notes for more info. Error and stacktrace: UnexpectedException: SObjectType is not available in DescribeSObjectResult: ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.DescribeSObjectResult'} ApexValue(DescribeSObjectResult) {status=INITIALIZED, declarationVertex=null, valueVertex=null, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.SObjectField'} ApexValue(SObjectField) {status=INITIALIZED, declarationVertex=null, valueVertex=null, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=ApexValue(ApexFieldDescribeMapValue) {status=INITIALIZED, declarationVertex=null, valueVertex=null, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.DescribeSObjectResult'} ApexValue(DescribeSObjectResult) {status=INITIALIZED, declarationVertex=null, valueVertex=null, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=SObjectType{associatedObjectType='null'} ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.SObjectType'} ApexValue(SObjectType) {status=INDETERMINANT, declarationVertex=SObjectType{associatedObjectType='null'} ApexStandardValue{apexType='Schema.SObjectType'} ApexValue(SObjectType) {status=INDETERMINANT, declarationVertex=VariableDeclaration{properties={FirstChild=false, BeginLine=4, Type=SObjectType, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=4, Name_CaseSafe=r, childIdx=1, BeginColumn=21, Name=r}}, valueVertex=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=getSObjectType, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, BeginLine=4, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=4, Name_CaseSafe=, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=89, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=}}}, chainedNames=[], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=getSObjectType, BeginLine=4, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=getsobjecttype, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=4, MethodName_CaseSafe=getsobjecttype, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=89, MethodName=getSObjectType}}, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=null, invocableExpression=null, method=null}, valueVertex=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=getSObjectType, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, BeginLine=4, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=4, Name_CaseSafe=, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=89, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=}}}, chainedNames=[], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=getSObjectType, BeginLine=4, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=getsobjecttype, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=4, MethodName_CaseSafe=getsobjecttype, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=89, MethodName=getSObjectType}}, resolvedValues={}, returnedFrom=null, invocableExpression=null, method=null}, invocableExpression=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=r.getDescribe, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, Names=[r], BeginLine=5, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=5, Name_CaseSafe=r, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=45, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=r}}}, chainedNames=[r], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=r.getDescribe, BeginLine=5, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=r.getdescribe, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=5, MethodName_CaseSafe=getdescribe, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=47, MethodName=getDescribe}}, method=Method{properties={FirstChild=false, BeginLine=2, IsStandard=true, DefiningType_CaseSafe=schema.sobjecttype, LastChild=false, DefiningType=Schema.SObjectType, Constructor=false, EndLine=2, Name_CaseSafe=getdescribe, childIdx=1, ReturnType=Schema.DescribeSObjectResult, Name=getDescribe, Arity=0, ReturnType_CaseSafe=schema.describesobjectresult, BeginColumn=38}}}, invocableExpression=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=flsDescribe.fields.getMap, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, Names=[flsDescribe, fields], BeginLine=6, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=6, Name_CaseSafe=flsdescribe.fields, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=51, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=flsDescribe.fields}}}, chainedNames=[flsDescribe, fields], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=flsDescribe.fields.getMap, BeginLine=6, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=flsdescribe.fields.getmap, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=6, MethodName_CaseSafe=getmap, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=70, MethodName=getMap}}, method=null}, invocableExpression=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=mfields.get, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, Names=[mfields], BeginLine=13, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=false, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=13, Name_CaseSafe=mfields, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=18, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=mfields}}}, chainedNames=[mfields], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=mfields.get, BeginLine=13, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=mfields.get, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=13, MethodName_CaseSafe=get, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=26, MethodName=get}}, method=null}, invocableExpression=MethodCallExpressionVertex{fullMethodName=getDescribe, referenceVertex=LazyVertex{result=ReferenceExpression{properties={FirstChild=true, BeginLine=13, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=13, Name_CaseSafe=, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=44, ReferenceType=METHOD, Name=}}}, chainedNames=[], properties={FirstChild=true, FullMethodName=getDescribe, BeginLine=13, FullMethodName_CaseSafe=getdescribe, DefiningType_CaseSafe=databasefls, LastChild=true, DefiningType=DatabaseFLS, EndLine=13, MethodName_CaseSafe=getdescribe, childIdx=0, BeginColumn=44, MethodName=getDescribe}}, method=Method{properties={FirstChild=false, BeginLine=2, IsStandard=true, DefiningType_CaseSafe=schema.sobjectfield, LastChild=false, DefiningType=Schema.SObjectField, Constructor=false, EndLine=2, Name_CaseSafe=getdescribe, childIdx=1, ReturnType=Schema.DescribeFieldResult, Name=getDescribe, Arity=0, ReturnType_CaseSafe=schema.describefieldresult, BeginColumn=36}}}: com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.FlsValidationRepresentation.setObject(FlsValidationRepresentation.java:86);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.convert(SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.java:183);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.checkForValidation(SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.java:77);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.FlsValidationCentral.checkSchemaBasedFlsValidation(FlsValidationCentral.java:71);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.AbstractFlsVisitor.afterVisit(AbstractFlsVisitor.java:67);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.ReadFlsRuleVisitor.afterVisit(ReadFlsRuleVisitor.java:54)



Am I doing something wrong here?

Not that I can tell.

For a security review I need to submit clean reports / document false positives is this a false positive?

Presumably, yes. Also, you should see if this bug is on GitHub; if so, subscribe, and if not, report it.
